# How to convert to date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I convert single date values ​​to date? For example in C# it is possible with the following;

```
int year = 2019;
int day = 1;
int month = 12;
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

How is it possible in SQL Server?

I'm not asking static string value conversion such as; `Convert(date, '2019-12-01')` because every element (year, month, day) in date must be parameter.

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server?

Comment: @gotgn it is 2008 and above

Comment: [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2012 version or later you can use [DateFromParts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4) = 2019;
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(2) = 1;
DECLARE @month  VARCHAR(2) = 12;

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( @year, @month, @day )
```

for 2008 version or higher you can use:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@month AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@day AS varchar) AS DATE)
```

Comment: I normally don't do that but I think my edit improves your answer. Feel free to roll back if you don't like it, my upvote will remain either way.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
 declare year varchar(5) = 2019;
 declare day varchar(2)  = 1;
 declare month varchar(2)  = 12;
 declare newDate DateTime = (select Convert(date, year + '-' + month + '-' + date));
```